# Parse error on input `<-'

Tags: haskell

My code looks like this:

```
threeByThree :: Sudoku -> [Block]
threeByThree sudoku = (chunksOf 9(concat(transpose(take 3 (rows sudoku)))++
    (transpose(take 3 rs))++(transpose xs)))
      where 
        rs <- drop 3 (rows sudoku)
        xs <- drop 3 rs
```

The error message I'm receiving:

```
Sudoku.hs:130:12: parse error on input `<-'
```

Which should be exactly at the first arrow. Am I missing the obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you meant:

```
where 
   rs = drop 3 (rows sudoku)
   xs = drop 3 rs
```

Note that `<-` has got a different meaning. It is used in the context of Monad desugaring.

Answer (score 1):

@Sibi has the correct answer to your specific problem.  I just wanted to briefly mention that this error usually means that you forgot to put `do` at the beginning of a `do` block:

```
-- Parse error on input `<-'
example1 =
    x <- m
    y <- n

-- How to fix the error:
example2 = do
    x <- m
    y <- n
```